# Insert multiple records into multiple tables using Dynamo DB transactions API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to use dynamo DB transaction API `TransactWriteItems` to insert multiple data into two different tables.

My use case is to insert records in two different tables i.e `PermissionTable` and `UserTable`

This transaction involves:

- Insertion of multiple records in `PermissionTable`
- Insert single record in `UserTable`

Below is the code snippet for the same.

`List<Permission> permissions` are the records to be inserted in `PermmissionTable`

`UserDetails user` is the records to be inserted in `UserTable`

```
 public boolean insertRecords(List<Permission> permissions, UserDetails user) {
    AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();
    TransactWriteItemsRequest request = new TransactWriteItemsRequest();
    
    // Create Transaction action for PermissionTable
    List<TransactWriteItem> permissionRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Permission permission : permissions) {
        final Map<String, AttributeValue> permissionRecord = convertToDDBMap(permission);
        Put permissionWrites = new Put().withTableName("PermissionTable")
                .withItem(permissionRecord);
        TransactWriteItem recordsToWrite = new TransactWriteItem().withPut(permissionWrites);
        permissionRecords.add(recordsToWrite);
    }

    // create transaction action for UserTable
    final Map<String, AttributeValue> userRecords = convertToDDBMap(user);
    Put userDetailsWrites = new Put().withTableName("UserTable")
          .withItem(userRecords);
    List<TransactWriteItem> writeRequests = new ArrayList<>();
    writeRequests.add(new TransactWriteItem().withPut(userRecords));
    writeRequests.addAll(permissionRecords);

    request.withTransactItems(writeRequests);
    request.withReturnConsumedCapacity(ReturnConsumedCapacity.TOTAL);

    try {
        dynamoDB.transactWriteItems(request);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
 }
```

The above function throws the following exception message

**Transaction request cannot include multiple operations on one item**

I looked into AWS documentation and examples, found some reference [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamodb-transactwriteitems/#:%7E:text=%22Transaction%20request%20cannot%20include%20multiple%20operations%20on%20one%20item%22).

Is there any alternate way to achieve this using Transaction API in dynamo DB?

Comment: No. Try to make the multiple operations on the one item in the same update.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid duplicating items in a single transaction as it's not allowed.

If you do not understand the exception, it's caused by 2 items which share the same primary key being inserted to the table in the same transaction request.

You should not have a valid use-case where you need to insert the same item twice in a table. I suggest checking your application logic.